# My Android app is not giving notification when app is in Backgroud

Tags: android

I am working on a Android App, in my app there is no notification coming when the app is in the background. However, the notification is coming when the app is in Foreground.

Any suggestions to make it workable for background as my latitude & longitude are not coming when in the background. Also, I am using a API too get the latitude & longitude.

Comment: you should use foreground service for this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Providing source code enables members to offer more specific advice. Thanks!